# Converting binary to hex: error only on 2-7

Tags: c++, binary, calculator

I'm converting 4digit binary to single digit hex using a basic switch-case statement and the code will not run for digits 0010-0111 for some reason and I have no idea why.

Here is what I have:

```
void BinHex() {
        int binin;
        cout << "Enter Binary(####): " << endl;
        cin >> binin;

        switch(binin){
                case 0000: cout << "Hex: 0" << endl; break;
                case 0001: cout << "Hex: 1" << endl; break;
                case 0010: cout << "Hex: 2" << endl; break;
                ...
        }
}
```

All numbers 0,1,8-15 work perfectly fine but the middle numbers do not. Any ideas on what could be causing this to error out/not run?

Comment: A switch with no {} ?

Comment: How have you declared your binin?

Comment: Yes, what is `binin`? If it is a number you can just use `0` to `15`, because internally the representation is the same. If it is string, I do not know if c++ supports them in switches. And yes, a number that begins with `0` is considered to be octal, not binary.

Comment: @Borgleader my actual switch statement contains the appropriate brackets. My apologies.

Comment: @SJuan76 my binin is a 4digit binary value (0000,0001,0010,...,1111)

Comment: Internally, all digits are binary (C-complement binary for signed). So `15` or `0x0f` or `017` are exactly the same number, with the same internal representation.

Comment: @BradenSmith do you enter them from cin as "10" for 2? That's not binary, that's decimal number.

Comment: @Slava no they are entered in as "0010"-"0111"

Comment: @BradenSmith that does not matter, cin will interpret that as decimal number, that's not really binary.

Comment: @Slava then what would be an appropriate form of input if the user chooses to convert from binary to hex? on the user end can they input as listed and then on my end have the case listed as 0b010 or what?

Comment: @BradenSmith standard streams do not handle binary numbers, so I would suggest enter it into string and then convert to binary number. Your representation of binary number by decimal with only 1 and 0 on it may work to some extend, but very limited.

Answer (score 5):

This case:

```
case 0010: cout<<"Hex: 2\n"; break;
```

Will not fire for `binin == 10`. It will fire for `binin == 8`, because `0010` is an **octal** literal. Just drop the leading `0`s so that the value gets interpreted as a decimal literal instead.